# Reset only the foreground color using terminfo

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape, terminfo

By using the ANSI sequence `Esc[39m` in a terminal, it is possible to clear the foreground color without altering other attributes like bold, underline, or the background color. For example:

```sh
echo -e "\e[31;1mRed and bold.\e[39m Bold only."
```

I would like to retrieve this sequence from a terminfo capability, but I'm unable to find it; when trying with `setaf 9`, it switches to bright colors by giving the sequence `Esc[91m`:

```
$ tput setaf 1 | xxd
00000000: 1b5b 3331 6d                             .[31m
$ tput setaf 9 | xxd
00000000: 1b5b 3931 6d                             .[91m
```

The only capability I found to reset the foreground color is `sgr0`, but it resets all the other attributes as well.

Is it possible to access these capabilities from terminfo ?

- Default foreground `Esc[39m`;
- Default background `Esc[49m`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to define it yourself.  [X/Open](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/cursesix.html) doesn't define it, and there's no established use for it.  Assuming you're using ncurses (which is [extensible](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/user_caps.5.html)), that can be done by modifying a terminal description and making up your own name for it, e.g.,

```
infocmp -x > myinfo.src
printf '\tresetf=\\E[39m,\n' >> myinfo.src
tic -x myinfo.src
```

(which would generally create **your** copy in [`$HOME/.terminfo/`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#home_terminfo)).