# How to reset $(tput bold) only?

Tags: shell, terminal, command-line-interface, termcap, terminfo

I’m making some post-formatting of a log for better readability.

Using regular expressions, my script recognizes some patterns in the stream and makes the correspondent text bold by inserting the `$(tput bold)` and `$(tput sgr0)` values at the beginning and at the end of the text respectively. The stream is not textual, it already contains some special formatting escape sequences like colors and so on.

```
    $(tput setaf 6)
    Part of this text can be $(tput bold)bold$(tput sgr0) but
    the rest of the text has lost its initial color.
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to turn off the bold mode only. Using `$(tput sgr0)` drops all the other current terminal settings to their default values, including the color.

I use `man terminfo` to know what “capname” I should use. For example, I know how to make some text italic, because the list contains both — the `sitm` capname to `enter_italic_mode` and the `ritm` capname to `exit_italic_mode`.

```
    $(tput setaf 6)
    Part of this text can be $(tput sitm)italic$(tput ritm) but
    the rest of the text still has its initial color.
```

I’d like to use the same approach to make text bold because the `terminfo` list contains the `bold` capname to `enter_bold_mode`. But there is neither “exit_bold_name” string variable nor a correspondent capname!

Am I missing something? Should I use another approach? In all the articles I have found on the Internet it is used the `sgr0` capname solution only.

Comment: is `tput smso` and `tput rmso` an acceptable approach?

Comment: I tried. `tput smso` makes the background dark and inverts the color of text. That’s not I’d like, unfortunately.

Comment: The documentation claims that `sc` and `rc` will save and restore position, but `tput sc; echo foo; tput bold; echo bar; tput rc; echo baz` seems to work in my terminal to restore attributes rather than position.

Comment: `printf "Hello, $(tput sc)$(tput bold)this$(tput rc) world. \n"` produces just `Hello,  world.` The word “this” disappears. Do I do something wrong?

Comment: No, what you are seeing is what I would expect.  I am extremely surprised to find that I do not see that behavior, but instead I see the attributes being saved and restored.  Very curious to know why.

Comment: Ah...I am seeing that behavior because the cursor position is at the bottom of the visible screen, so the scrolling effect has an impact.

Comment: The behavior is terminal-dependent.  Restoring attributes on cursor-restore happens to be something that VT100s did (and derived stuff such as xterm do -- though for others, *ymmv*).

Comment: Not all terminals support an explicit undo for **bold**.  VT100 did not.  Conventional terminfo took info account what was common to many terminals.

Comment: This is the same type of question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68893646/reset-only-the-foreground-color-using-terminfo/68914665#68914665).  I'd mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: The link you’ve provided does not answer the question. When I make some text bold, the text already has a color that is unknown and arbitrary. Resetting to the default color, as suggested there, in fact, is the same as `tput sgr0`. And, unlike the author of that question, I don’t know the hard codes that I could use.